# Create CSV for each domain

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I know this not the proper string because it outputs containing the header. I also need to create a CSV for each domain.

I have a list of emails in CSV

```
Emails
-----
John@abc.com
Stacy@abc.com
Bob@xyz.com
```

I have another list of domains in CSV

```
Domains
-----
abc.com
xyz.com
```

I would like to create new CSV files for each domain. For example
abc.csv

```
Emails
-----
John@abc.com
Stacy@abc.com
```

while xyz.csv would be

```
Emails
-----
Bob@xyz.com
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$emails = Import-Csv emails.csv
$domains = Import-Csv domains.csv

Foreach ($i in $domains) {
    $emails | Where-Object Email -like *$i | Export-Csv "test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the giant code block, but I can't figure out how to post tables normally without throwing a warning about code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is due to properties.  Assuming your CSV files look like this:

[image]

If they do, then when we read from .csv, we'll get an array of items with `emails` properties and `domains` properties.

Meaning we need to modify your loop like this to iterate through them:

```
#added `.Domains` here
Foreach ($i in $domains.Domains) {  
    $FileName = "UsersOf$($i)Domain.csv"
    $emails | Where-Object Emails -like "*$i" | `
        Export-Csv $fileName -NoTypeInformation
}
```

With this small change (you were so close!) it now creates the expected CSV Files.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly thank you. Just so I know what is the backtick for on $emails line?

Comment: Backticks in PowerShell are used to wrap a line wherever you want.  I did it to make it fit without having to scroll around in StackOverflow's window.

Comment: In this case you can safely remove that backtick, because PowerShell accepts line continuation after a `|`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `Domains` csv file at all.. Just parse the domain names from the email addresses:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\emails.csv' | 
Group-Object {($_.Emails -split '@')[-1]} | 
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path ('D:\Test\{0}.csv' -f ($_.Name -split '\.')[0]) -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Result are two files:

**abc.csv**

```
"Emails"
"John@abc.com"
"Stacy@abc.com"
```

**xyz.csv**

```
"Emails"
"Bob@xyz.com"
```